# Does DolphinDB have a function to calculate the correlation between two columns?

Tags: sql, database, dolphindb

I want to calculate the correlation between two columns, does DolphinDB have such functions? It seems that the function "corr" only apply to the vector. I get the error as below:

```py
corr(x, y) => getDoubleConst method not supported
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If x, y are two columns of an in-memory table t, the correct script is as below:

```py
corr(t.x, t.y)   //here t.x and t.y are vectors.
```